# Jenkins - downstream commit triggers upstream job

Tags: jenkins, version-control, continuous-integration

I am in need for a solution that provides a way, to trigger an upstream job if there was a change (new commit) to repositories triggering downstream jobs.

Let's visualize: there are 4 jobs: A, B, C, D.

B, C, D are triggered(individually) by commits to their(individual) repositories (triggered via Poll SCM)

And now I want job A to trigger all the jobs: B, C, D.

But I want job A to trigger B, C and D only if there is a new commit to B or C or D.

How can I achieve this? I'd like to leave B, C and D jobs intact.

Comment: To clarify your question, the job A is using its own repo? And you want to trigger this job if the repo B or C or D is updated?

Comment: A isn't using any cvs. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to setup Job A to Poll SCM for the B, C, and D repositories. Then setup job B, C, and D with build triggers to build after job A is built. You would want to remove automatic polling from jobs B, C, and D, otherwise both A and the respective B, C, D job would fire and you would get duplicate runs.

However, the above solution would always fire off jobs B, C, and D anytime a commit was made to any of the three repositories. If you ONLY want to fire off the respective job for which the commit was made, you will have to add some other logic in job A to detect which job to fire off. In this case, you would not want to add a trigger in jobs B,C,D to build after job A. Rather, in job A you would want to add a post-build action to build other projects based on a certain condition (possibly using the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)). The condition would need to be set using some other programmatic build step (groovy code, shell script, etc).

Comment: But I want it to run once a day, and if changes found, run the job. Not run it on every commit ;-)

Comment: Easy enough to do. Just set Job A to run once a day instead of periodically polling SCM.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can use the [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin).

It will allow the job A to use several SCM sources:

- Repo B
- Repo C
- Repo D

Next, you just have to set a cron expression on the job A to pool these repos.

Answer (score 0):

The [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) has an option on the main job to poll the SCM of its sub-jobs.

[image: Multi job polling]

If you make your A job a multi-job, you can enable this setting and then add jobs B, C, and D as phases of the job to be executed sequentially or in parallel. You can even tell it NOT to build B, C, or D, if their SCM has no changes, if you so wish.

You can still add normal build steps, too, so your original steps in job A can be performed before the B, C, and D phases are started.

It is important to note that using the Multijob plugin requires the main job to be executing while its sub-jobs are running. This means you need a minimum of 2 executors on the system.